# How to resolve this cast to pointer of a different size warning?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I'm trying to troubleshoot some warnings in my C code compiled with -std=gnuc99.

```
void function.. (char *argument)
{
  int hour;

  hour = (int) (struct tm *)localtime(&current_time)->tm_hour;

  if(hour < 12)
  {
      do...something...
  }
}
```

The warning

```
 warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 hour = (int) (struct tm *)localtime(&current_time)->tm_hour;
              ^
```

What I assume is happning here is that localtime is not a pointer and it's not the same size as int?

Comment: Operator Precedence. `((cast) pointer)->field` is not the same as `(cast) (pointer->field)`. Add the parens to figure out how the parser is seeing your code.

Comment: int is 32-bits.  pointer is 32- or 64-bits, depending.

Comment: Would this be Type Pruning? I tried and got no warning with (int) ((struct tm *)localtime(&current_time))->tm_hour;

Comment: If so, @amon, post your suggestion as the answer. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

`localtime(&current_time)->tm_hour` has type `int` . You then cast this to `struct tm *`, producing the warning.  In general, conversion between pointers and `int` is not meaningful and may cause undefined behaviour.

To avoid this error, remove the casts:

```
hour = localtime(&current_time)->tm_hour;
```